# How can i make Foundation tooltip show on focus?

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

this is what i am doing.

```
<input  data-tooltip  data-width="350" class="has-tip tip-left" title="enter name" type="text" />
<script>
$(document).foundation();
```

tooltip is working fine on hover to input but i want to call it on focus.
please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".has-tip").focus(function(){
  $(this).foundation();
});
```

But make sure, you may want to hide the tooltip on focus out. for that you may do this

```
$(".has-tip").blur(function(){

//may be you can hide the tooltip or call the hide function if any.
});
```

Note, calling events may change according to the jquery version.

Comment: Thanks its working when focused and then hovered.
i need tooltip on the first time focus.

Answer (score 1):

```
Foundation.libs.tooltip.showTip( jQuery( ".has-tip" ) );
```

You might want to add an #id to the span to make a more specific selector for the showTip function.

See: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js

Answer (score -1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/beLFt/1/)**

Try this..

```
$('input').focus(function() {
     $('div').show();
}).focusout(function() {
    $('div').hide();
});
```