# Show Foundation 5 Tooltip on Click

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation

I have a tooltip through foundation 5 on a span, like so:

`<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip tip-top" title="My tool tip"><i class="fi-pricetag-multiple size-21"></i></span>`

This works fine. However, what I would like to do is only show the tooltip when a user clicks the span (instead of hovering). Then it closes when you click the a close button. I'm able to get halfway there when I add `data-tooltip-open-event-type="touch"` but this adds two tooltips and it still disapears when I hover away.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. It seems odd that foundation 5 wouldn't have some sort of pop out for interactive content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just needed to figure this out for myself too.

**To show:**

```
Foundation.libs.tooltip.getTip($('#yourId')).show()
```

**To hide:**

```
Foundation.libs.tooltip.getTip($('#yourId')).hide()
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you achieved this with this code and open-event-type?

Answer (score 0):

[Ron Marcelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4372660/ron-marcelle) has found it in [Foundation tooltip source](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js):

> Foundation.libs.tooltip.showTip( jQuery( ".has-tip" ) );

Taken from [How can i make Foundation tooltip show on focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462370/how-can-i-make-foundation-tooltip-show-on-focus)