# Foundation 5: Run tooltip only on click (like joyride style)

Tags: javascript, css, tooltip, zurb-joyride, zurb-foundation-5

I want to have a tooltip using [foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/) that appears **only on click (disable on hover)** and that **can be closed**.

Basically something to the first tooltip you see in [this joyride example](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html) but without using joyride.

I couldn't find a way to fix it and documentation is scarce for it, How could this be possibly hacked around?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with jQuery? http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @simpe tried jQuery, JS, CSS, using the Foundation.lib.tooltip prototype. Nothing worked.

Comment: When you want it to be able to close, do you mean by click, or a cross or something?

Comment: Perhaps this can be of some sort of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163088/show-foundation-5-tooltip-on-click

Comment: @AwesomeGuy yes on click (cross or any other clickable element of choice)

Comment: @simpe i've tried that already, it only blinked and disappeared back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you would have to modify the source of the foundation library you're working with. In the Foundation.lib.tooltip it sets up an event listener for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. You would want to delete and only have listeners to `touchstart` (for mobile / touchscreen devices) & a mouseclick (which I'm assuming is what `MSPointerDown` does).

reference: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js#L62

I think you could also clear the logic on lines 86 - 92 that only follows the tooltip if the user has hovered over the tooltip for a certain duration

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js#L86-L92

Comment: Lidral-Porter I thought about it, but is there a way around so I don't have to play with the source code?

Comment: Certainly, it gets a little trickier. You would have to remove the event listeners for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. To do so, you have to call `.removeEventListener`, which takes 2 arguments: a type (i.e. "click") & the listener you want to remove. This second argument has to be a reference to the same function that is handling the event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener for examples / more details